# How do I change the LayoutParameters of a TextView in a RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, textview, android-relativelayout

I need to dynamically change the size of a `TextView` and the `Gravity` of the text it contains. The TextView is initially located at the top-left corner inside a `RelativeLayout`. I need to expand it to cover the whole RelativeLayout and display its text content centered. Then I need to return it to its initial settings.

My issue is I am not able to get back to the initial settings: the height of the TextView keeps the height of the RelativeLayout and the text content of the TextView stays centered on the vertical axis (the width and horizontal alignment are correctly reset).

Here is an extract of the XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/Row0">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/A1"
        android:tag="A1"
        android:padding="@dimen/default_cell_padding"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="setGUICellSelected"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/default_cell_margin">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1"
            android:id="@+id/A11"
            android:tag="A11"
            android:textSize="@dimen/tipFontSize"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
```

Here is the code (rearranged to show the logical flow):

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutLayoutParamsCenteredInParent = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
...
textView.setLayoutParams(relativeLayoutLayoutParamsCenteredInParent);
textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
...
textView.setLayoutParams(relativeLayoutLayoutParams);
textView.setGravity(Gravity.TOP + Gravity.LEFT);
```

Setting positive integer values for the width and height in the constructor of the `relativeLayoutLayoutParams` variable instead of `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT` has no impact.

Saving the initial LayoutParamaters of TextView "A11" in the `relativeLayoutLayoutParams` variable instead of using a constructor as above does not work either.

How should I set up the relativeLayoutLayoutParams variable in order to get the textView back to its original size and its text content aligned left and top as it was before expanding it to match the parent? Or should I use something else than the LayouParameters?

***** EDIT *****

The issue happens for API=15, not for higher API levels.

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Maybe the problem is in other layout elements?

Comment: @ArtemMostyaev I also use `textView.setBackgroundColor()`, and  `tetView.setTextAppearance()` to change the `TextSize`, `TextColor` and `TextStyle` of the text content. However this works fine and has no influence on the behaviour of the application (these methods are also successfully applied to other TextViews inside the RelativeLayout).

Comment: Hm.. I don't know. You can try to comment some part of your code and xml layout then to catch the reason.